# Css selector to get entire table row (tr)

Tags: css

I have html like this below - and do not have access to modify it beyond setting a class or id on the first "td" in the row.  Is there a way to target the entire row, or get both "td" elements in the row?

```html
<tr>
  <td width="50%" valign="top"><font class="subheader"><span class="eField">membershipCode</span>&nbsp;</font></td>
  <td width="50%" valign="top"><font class="text">Testing&nbsp;</font></td>
 </tr>
```

Part of this goes out in Email, so I'd rather avoid Javascript if possible.  I tried this css, but no luck so far:

```css
<style type="text/css">
td span.eField { 
display:none;
}
td span.eField+td { 
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Is there any way to do this using pure css?

NOTE:  I only want to target rows containing the "eField" elements - I can hide the element itself, but can't get the next  or the entire row.  So I don't want to hide all rows in the table, just a select few.

Thanks,

-Jim

Comment: WANT to select first `td` of every `row`??

Comment: Try `$('table tr')` selector.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal That's jQuery (built with javascript), which the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Edited my post for more clarity - only looking for rows with an "eField" element in them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed You can do it using normal css like the following fiddle demonstrates:

using the following two methods

```
table tr td
```

or

```
table tr
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLynh5n1/

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you're trying to do.
But can't you just use:

```
tr,
td {
    css:css !important;
}
```

?

Comment: you have to be really careful with `!important`. if you want to know more about why to take care about that statement, google for `specifishity`

Comment: specificity you mean? @Joshua

Comment: @DanielCasserly the real term is specificity, but there is a blog where specificity is explained with fishes and stuff, so it's called specifishity ;)

Comment: Cool, do you have  a link to the blog?

Comment: If anyone is still looking for the *fish* thing  https://www.specifishity.com/specifishity.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are try to select the parent of the span with class eField. 
CSS has the descendant selector but not the other way around.

a > img { border: none; }  - valid - all img directly under a

a < img { border: none; } - not valid - all a directly above img

[Refer this link](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)